# LinkPager for ajax generated results

Tags: ajax, yii2

Is there a way to change the Url generated by the LinkPager in Yii2?
I have a page with results that are loaded with ajax when the search field is updated. But my pagination buttons links to a new page with the ajax-call url.

I looked in the files, and it seems like this function generates the url

```
public function createUrl($page, $pageSize = null, $absolute = false)
```

and that is not option to change. What is the way to solve this problem?

My results page is at the front page, but the pagination buttons links to ajax/results?page=2&page-size=10.

Comment: You should be able to create your own pager that does what you need and pass it to the gridvie. You can also remove the pager from the gridview and call your own pager to show on screen. Can you explain the full problem, maybe there is another simpler solution.

Comment: I'm not using grid view, i'm only using the pager with my own query. I could create my own, but i would think that the Yii-crew has a solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What can be more elegant then extending a class and replacing the renderPageButton function with your own :).

Another way, probably more the yii2 way :) if you take a look at LinkPager you will see that it is not responsible of creating the URLS. Pagination is https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/data/Pagination.php#L257 The createUrl function in Pagination creates the URL and it takes into consideration the $route defined for the pagination object. If there is no $route defined then it takes the current controller's route. So by setting up $route for the pagination you can set the URL the buttons will go to.

Comment: I knew they had a solution for it. Don't know how i missed it tho. Thanks man.

Comment: No worries, right now (this exact moment) I am actually working on a custom pager so I was on top of things :).